# “Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages with APT

Tags: apt

Can't install anything other than 'sudo' because of the error package not found Anyone have any ideas? I'm posting here because nearly all of my issues have been fixed, mainly wanting to install Steam and some other applications such as leafpad. Keep in mind, I have been using Ubuntu, but recently changed to Debian, just to try it out.

If you need further information just leave a comment, thanks. By the way, I've checked every single other similar questions and none of them help.

Debian Jessie 8.6

Error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install <package>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package <package>
```

Sources.list File:
    #

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD     Binary-1 20160917-14:25]/ jessie contrib main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 8.6.0 _Jessie_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1     20160917-14:25]/ jessie contrib main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: What you mean "other than sudo"?? Post some error texts

Comment: Done. By "other than sudo" I mean I can't install anything like LeafPad and even just basic things like Steam. When installing Debian I unticked the box that installs necessary packages because of my unstable internet connection at the time, therefore, I had to install Sudo, which was the only thing I managed to get working.

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update`? What is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`? is your sources.list file correct?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` Will try this. Not sure how to check my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.

Comment: you will find it under /etc/apt/ directory. post contents if you want , or google it

Comment: Will do in about 12 hours or so, got to go to sleep and do some stuff, will be updated soon.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou When I go onto /etc/apt/directory, there is a sources.list folder but nothing in there.

Comment: @HypoCheese post `ls /etc/apt/`. File sources.list usually exists just under /etc/apt and not inside sources.list folder. You might missing sources.list file

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing sources.list file.
Go to /etc/apt and create a new file with name sources.list

I suppose you are at Debian Stable , so put these content inside:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

If you want in the future to try Debian Testing (most recent apps, kernel, etc) you need to add testing repos line in this file , like this:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free

deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib non-free
```

Just for comparison, have a look in my /etc/apt folder:

```
root@debian:/home/gv/Desktop/PythonTests# ls -al /etc/apt 
total 56
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Jan  4 19:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 131 root root 12288 Jan  4 19:17 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  5 00:38 apt.conf.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    99 Dec 27 08:42 listchanges.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   218 Jan  1 21:53 preferences
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 12  2016 preferences.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1558 Jan  1 22:00 sources.list
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan  1 21:38 sources.list.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4171 Jan  1 21:38 trusted.gpg
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec 27 02:58 trusted.gpg.d
```

Comment: I found a sources.list file and it has this content inside. Added it to my description under the question, take a look.

Comment: You sources.list file is different than mine. Back up of your file and try my file with copy paste, don't miss anything. Let me know for the results. Also let me know if a file preferences (just file, not directory) exists under your /etc/apt, like my list.

Comment: I found a file named preferences.d, but that's all, the other folders and files include: apt.conf.d, listchanges.conf, preferences.d, sources.list, sources.list.d, sources.list.save, trusted.gpg.d.

Comment: Ok. Did you try to replace contents of your sources.list with the lines i post? Don't forget after the saving of the file (requires root access) to do a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: With the file sources.list do I just copy in the first section of text or all of the text that is in a greyish box.

Comment: Could you give me a run down on how to edit the file? Whenever I edit it in Libre it says "User doesn't have sufficient rights" or something along those lines.

Comment: In your sources.list add # in front of all existed lines (this will disable your existed entries) and copy paste the first block on my answer (all lines that refer jessie in my answer , not the ones in second block referring testing )

Comment: from a regular user terminal run `gksu libreoffice &` to open libre in root mode.

Comment: @HypoCheese Any news?

Comment: I'll try it in an hour, not on the PC currently! Sorry.

Comment: I am unable to access my PC today or tomorrow due to certain issues, I will try to get back to you ASAP. Thanks.

Comment: I'm attempting to do `gksu libreoffice &` but It says `gksu: command not found`.

Comment: Try `sudo libreoffice &`. I suggest you to install also gksu (`apt-get install gksu`)

Comment: I tried installing GKSU but it said `package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.  This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.` By the way, I did as instructed and still `E: Unable to locate package (package name).` Didn't work for Steam.

Comment: Have you try to install for example mousapd and other pkgs  ? Does it work with other packages?

Comment: Works with none so far, I've tried steam and leafpad.

Comment: Seems strange. Are you sure you have internet access to this machine? Does any of this commands works? `apt-get download leafpad` , `apt list agrep` or `apt list "agrep"` . As well in which country are you ? You could try to replace the httpredir.debiab,org  part from lines  `deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib` to a more country specific mirror found here: https://www.debian.org/mirror/list . This makes no sense since httpredir should do the redirection automatically , but you could try to manually enter a local mirror for testing.

Comment: Hey, I'm from Australia, `apt-get download leafpad` comes up with the package not found error, `apt list agrep` or `apt list "agrep"` comes up with `Listing... Done`.

Comment: @HypoCheese Can you try to use your old entries of sources.list by adding also this line to your file: `deb http://ftp.au.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free`. Then `apt-get update`. What it gives with `apt list "xfce4-*"`...?

Comment: Can you tell me how to just get rid of Debian through partitions so I can then, later on, reinstall it with all packages ready?